# How to properly insert elements into a table using PSQL SQL SHELL

Tags: psql

I'm trying to add a user to a table using SQL SHELL (psql), but I can't see where I'm wrong.

```
membros_l0j3=> \d usuario;

                                 Tabela "public.usuario"
 Coluna |       Tipo        | Collation | Nullable |               Default

--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------

 id     | integer           |           | not null | nextval('usuario_id_seq'::regclass)

 email  | character varying |           | not null |

 senha  | character varying |           | not null |

═ndices:

    "usuario_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

    "usuario_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)



membros_l0j3=> INSERT INTO USUARIO (email, senha) VALUES ("test@gmail.com", "pass01");

ERROR:  column "test@gmail.com" does not exist

LINHA 1: INSERT INTO USUARIO (email, senha) VALUES ("test@gmail.com",...
```

I've searched a lot and yet I've not found a way to get it right.